# I want two divs to move dynamically with one another

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a sentenced with a solid border around it. When I the sentence, the border changes, adjusting to fit the sentence. I also have a pink circle. I would like the pink circle to be in the top right corner of the border around the sentence no matter the length of the sentence - I want the circle to move dynamically with the border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Family Tree Creator</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="nameone">Core water is soooo good!!</div>
        <div class="circleone"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
.nameone {
  border: 3px solid darkgray;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

.circleone{
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

[image: Website Image]

I'm new to css and html so I tried several variations of placing s inside of one another but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would apply `flex` to the container (in your example `body`, but I recommend to create a seperate container div), with the usual settings for centering its only child (see below).

Then apply `position: relative` to `.nameone` to make it act as the position anchor for the absolutely positioned `.circleone` div which you have to move *inside*  the `.nameone` div to be its child, with `top` and `right` settings as below to place the circle into the top right corner of its parent:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nameone {
  border: 3px solid darkgray;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.circleone {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Family Tree Creator</title>
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nameone">Core water is soooo good!!
    <div class="circleone"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Another solution would be to create the circle by adding a *pseudo element* (`.nameone::after`) in CSS with very similar settings as above, but *without* the circle div in the HTML code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nameone {
  border: 3px solid darkgray;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nameone::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Family Tree Creator</title>
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nameone">Core water is soooo good!!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - the bottom one, thank you @Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Taken two screenshots with different text. [Guess this is what you wanted](https://imgur.com/a/YZEmI0h)

Create a separate `<div>` for the  text and place it inside the class `.nameone`. Place the circle's div i.e the class `.circleone` before the text div. And style the class `.circleone` as `float:right` in css. Add `<div style = "clear:both"></div>` after the class `.circleone` in html.

For testing purpose, I've added the css inside the  tags. You can remove it; place it in a separate css file and modify according to your requirement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Family Tree Creator</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
    .nameone {
  border: 3px solid darkgray;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

.circleone{
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="nameone">
        <div class="circleone"></div>
        <div style = "clear:both;"></div>
        <div>Core water is soooo good!Core water is soooo good!</div>
        </div>
        

</body>
</html>
```